# Windows resume loader error

Tags: windows-7, post

I work on a service desk and got a call today about an error a user was having: `Windows resume loader failed` so I attempted some trouble shooting in the following:

- Had user hard reboot; error still occurred but user was able to attempt to start normally; after normal Windows start it threw the Windows resume loader error again
- So I thought about starting in safe mode, I had the user restart again; got him to the safe mode start and had him attempt to reset in safe mode; it ended up freezing his keyboard and he was unable to choose an option; so I did some research and found out that he would have to reset his [capacitors](http://informertech.com/how-to-fix-windows-resume-loader-on-windows-7/)
- Had user reset the capacitors by unplugging the computer and holding down the power button for about 20 seconds; user still got the same error

So my question is, is there anything else I could have done in order to further assist this user, also how do you fix this issue?

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise, it's a government laptop, so that might make this a little more complicated

Comment: Ok. I'll try to help. What happens if the user presses option 2 or `Delete restoration data and proceed to system boot menu`?

Comment: Well I didn't go that far because my job entails me to only have a certain amount of Administrative privileges. What I was able to do is troubleshoot to the point where I knew the error wouldn't go away. Basically I just want to know if there's anything more I could have done?

Comment: There is not much more you could've done without being there especially if the keyboard was not working.

Comment: @TheKB That's kind of what I figured, how do you fix this issue anyways?

Comment: The "fix" if it only happens once is to press `2` and move on. This only indicates that the hibernation/sleep file is corrupted. Pressing `2` will just normally boot windows.

Comment: Fair enough, post it as an answer and I'll give you the bounty

Comment: I have posted it as an answer.  I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the `Windows Resume Loader Error` press `2` when presented with options. This will discard any corrupted hibernation/sleep files and boot windows normally.

Comment: I can award you the bounty in 23 hours.

Comment: @13aal No problem, again glad I could help.